# Connect Oracle Autonomous Database in Microsoft Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, oracle

Anyone in here have already connected Oracle Autonomous DB in Azure Data Factory?

We are trying to implement some data copies from SQL Server to Oracle, but I am not able to reach Oracle Autonomous Database, using standard host, port, service name and credentials. Maybe any security layer related to the Wallet is missing? I can't find any documents explaining.

The error when trying to connect is:
ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead.

Thanks, Guilherme

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this issue out? We're trying to setup the same connection from ADF and getting that error too. Wondering if you were able to resolve it through ADF?

Comment: Hi @JodyClaggett, sorry for the delay. I gave up due to lack of time I had to develop the solution and build my integration using Talend (free version). It's working for me temporarilly. Anyway, I've raised an idea on Azure portal, so Microsoft can someday build a connector. You can vote to support this idea: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/41900596-azure-data-factory-and-oracle-autonomous-database

Comment: Someone in that idea suggested to follow these instructions, but I didn't try yet > https://manavpurohit1.medium.com/azure-data-lake-to-oracle-autonomous-data-warehouse-2a53cb5f723b

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to perform a network trage on Oracle DB ?
Connection Dead looks to be that for some reasons a established connection lost contact. This happens when you use a Oracle Listener which redirects the a different Port and you use a firewall - for example default port 1521 is redirected to a free port - like 34238 etc. In that case client process lost connection since DB server process port is blocked by firewall and Client cant transfer data to port

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your time on this! To be honest, I have a very small background related to infrastructure. But related to my question, I have been getting some help from Oracle and Microsoft, and this kind of connection seems not viable at the moment, so I am planning to use other integration tools.